# What is `as` in type expressions for?

Tags: types, ocaml, type-alias

The Ocaml 5 manual section 11.4 says a typeexpr can have the form `typexpr as ' ident`.

What are these `as` aliases for?

Here are some examples that compile:

```
type 'a x = 'a as int

type y = 'a as int`
```

At first I thought `as` aliases were like type-level `let`s, but I couldn't figure out how to use the new type variable, or how this would differ from `constraint`:

```
type x = 'a as int in ('a, 'a) (* doesn't compile *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases (`_ as _`) at the type level have three relatively distinct use cases:

- Local abbreviations:

```ml
val triple_printer: (Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit as 'pr) -> 'pr -> 'pr -> (Format.formatter -> ('a * 'a * 'a) -> unit
```

Here `_ as 'pr` avoid to repeat the complex type printer type for a single element without resorting to an explicit type definition.

- Recursive types: in particular, recursive types happen quite naturally with polymorphic variants and objects.
  For instance

```ml
type 'a tree = [ `Leaf of 'a | `Node of 'tree list ] as 'tree
let x :  let x : _ tree = `Node [`Leaf 1; `Node [`Leaf 2; `Leaf 3]]
class c x = object val x = x method incr = {< x = x + 1 >} end
let incr (c: < incr: 'self; .. > as 'self) = c#incr
let test = incr (new c 0)
```

Note that outside of polymorphic variants and objects, equi-recursive types need to be explicitly enabled with the `rectypes` option.

- A limited form of constraints, which is mostly useful when defining family of type with an open row type variable:

```ml
type 'a t = <x:int; y :int; .. > as 'a
```

is equivalent to

```ml
type 'a t = 'a
  constraint 'a = <x:int; y:int; .. >
```

and is necessary because the `..` hides an implicit type variable that must be bound in the definition.
However, it is generally simpler to define the closer form in this case

```ml
type t = < x : int; y : int >
```

and use definition inlining when one need the open variant:

```ml
let f (c: < t; .. >) = c#x + c#y
```

Moreover, the explicit form is more general in complex case. For instance, I can summarize the type of

```
let f x = x#step_1#step_2#step_3
```

by defining a sequence of constraints

```ml
type 'a t = 'r
  constraint 'a = <step_1:'s1; .. >
  constraint 's1 = <step_2:'s2; ..>
  constraint 'r = <step_3:'r; ..>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your examples don't compile:

```
# type 'a x = 'a as int;;
Error: Syntax error
# type y = 'a as int`;;
Error: Syntax error
```

The purpose of `as` is to give a name to some part of a type being defined, so that the name can be used elsewhere in the same type definition. This allows types to have recursive substructures. I believe this is useful mostly when working with exotic types where the `-rectypes` flag has been given.

Here is an example of a recursive type consisting of a list whose elements are lists of the same type. As far as I can figure, the only values of this type are lists of lists of lists of ... of empty lists.

```
$ rlwrap ocaml -rectypes
OCaml version 4.14.0
Enter #help;; for help.

# type abc = 'a list as 'a;;
type abc = 'a list as 'a
# ([] : abc);;
- : abc = []
# ([[]] : abc);;
- : abc = [[]]
# ([[[]]] : abc);;
- : abc = [[[]]]
# ([[]; []] : abc);;
- : abc = [[]; []]
# ([[]; [[]]] : abc);;
- : abc = [[]; [[]]]
#
```

**Update**

Your examples don't compile with OCaml 5.0.0

```
$ cat m.ml
type 'a x = 'a as int
$ cat n.ml
type y = 'a as int`
$ ocamlopt -version
5.0.0
$ ocamlopt -c m.ml
File "m.ml", line 1, characters 18-21:
1 | type 'a x = 'a as int
                      ^^^
Error: Syntax error
$ ocamlopt -c n.ml
File "n.ml", line 1, characters 15-18:
1 | type y = 'a as int`
                   ^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Comment: The examples I gave compile using `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt` version 5.0.0. As you show, the toplevel doesn't like them.